# WebStorm reports "Unresolved function or method" - how to get rid of this?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm working on an application using WebStorm and occasionally I've seen warnings of the "unresolved variable" variety.  These I have fixed, thanks to the StackOverflow community, by using JSDoc, either the `@param` or `@namespace` labels.

However I have just ONE more "unresolved function or method" to fix.  In my app.js file I have the following line:

```
const app = express().use(bodyParser.json());
```

WebStorm flags up the `.use` function as an "unresolved function or method".  I've tried resolving this by using JSDoc as follows:

```
/**
 * @namespace express()
 * @namespace express().use()
 * */
```

I put this above the `const app = express().use(bodyParser.json());` line, but it doesn't make a difference.

Is there another way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that the express methods list is generated dynamically, and it's not possible to resolve these properties using static code analysis. Running `npm i @types/express` should solve the problem